# If inside if in php

Tags: php, if-statement

I have code like this

```
foreach($all_meta_for_user as $key=>$val){
  if (array_key_exists ('invoice_company_name', $val) 
      && array_key_exists('invoice_street', $val) 
      && array_key_exists('invoice_street_number', $val) 
      && array_key_exists('invoice_post_code', $val) 
      && array_key_exists('invoice_city', $val) 
      && array_key_exists('invoice_country', $val) 
      && array_key_exists('invoice_nip', $val) ): ?>
```

What I'd like to do is : `&& array_key_exists('invoice_nip', $val)` part should be 'if'ed'.

I have two types of account - individual and company,

so when someone is individual user, the last statement with nip is not necessary.

When someone has company account, its needed.

Any ideas? :))

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do one thing here as:

change your last condition as

```
&& ($accType=='individual' || array_key_exists('invoice_nip', $val))
```

In this way last condition would be checked only if your `$accType` is not individual

```
$accType='company';

foreach($all_meta_for_user as $key=>$val){
    if (array_key_exists ('invoice_company_name', $val) 
        && array_key_exists('invoice_street', $val) 
        && array_key_exists('invoice_street_number', $val) 
        && array_key_exists('invoice_post_code', $val) 
        && array_key_exists('invoice_city', $val) 
        && array_key_exists('invoice_country', $val) 
        && ($accType=='individual' || array_key_exists('invoice_nip', $val)) ): ?>
```

I guess this is what you are asking for?

Happy Coding!!!

Answer (score 2):

Try with `in_array` like

```
$array = array('invoice_company_name','invoice_street','invoice_street_number',...);
if(in_array($val,$array)) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its better to pass dynamical array as parameter to this function and then parse

e.g for company, the types will be

```
$typesArr = array('invoice_company_name','invoice_street','invoice_street_number','invoice_post_code','invoice_city','invoice_country','invoice_nip')
```

and for induividual it will be like

```
$typesArr = array('invoice_company_name','invoice_street','invoice_street_number','invoice_post_code','invoice_city','invoice_country')
```

Code to check this:

```
foreach($all_meta_for_user as $key=>$val){ 
    foreach($typesArr as $type){ 
      if(array_key_exists($type,$val){ 
               // blah blah 
       } 
    } 
}
```